# Uso de 'this' no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Assim como existe o 'this' no JavaScript, qual é o equivalente no Delphi? E como eu usaria? Quero substituir o 'UniButtonX' de cada procedimento por um 'this' equivalente ao botão clicado.

```
procedure TUniForm1.UniButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var numero : string;
begin
   numero := UniEdit1.Text;
   UniEdit1.Text := numero + UniButton1.Caption;
end;

procedure TUniForm1.UniButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var numero : string;
begin
   numero := UniEdit1.Text;
   UniEdit1.Text := numero + UniButton2.Caption;
end;
```

Comment: O `this` do Delphi se chama `self`. Mas no caso em questão ele se refere ao form, já que todos os métodos são do TUniForm1. Como você mesmo viu, o botão vem pelo parâmetro Sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui... é o 'sender'.

```
procedure TUniForm1.UniButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var numero : string;
begin
   numero := UniEdit1.Text;
   UniEdit1.Text := numero + TUniButton(sender).Caption;
end;

procedure TUniForm1.UniButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var numero : string;
begin
   numero := UniEdit1.Text;
   UniEdit1.Text := numero + TUniButton(sender).Caption;
end;
```

Porém ainda tenho a dúvida de como eu poderia criar uma função para quando chamá-la no OnClick de cada botão, executá-la com o 'sender' do botão clicado.

Consegui de novo...

```
procedure TUniForm1.clique(Sender: TObject);
var numero : string;
begin
   numero := UniEdit1.Text;
   UniEdit1.Text := numero + TUniButton(sender).Caption;
end;

procedure TUniForm1.UniButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   clique(TUniButton(sender));
end;

procedure TUniForm1.UniButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   clique(TUniButton(sender));
end;
```

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de otimização do código, por favor, responda/comente. O que estou fazendo é uma calculadora em Delphi.

Comment: É possível utilizar um mesmo método para evento de mais de um botão, isto evitaria de ter um UniButtonClick para cada botão.

Comment: Verdade! Tinha esquecido disso. Obrigado!